# my columns not in opposite with using float:right

Tags: html, css

So i am using `aside` html5 semantic to make columns.
I wanna have them on the left and right
So i just use class to use `float:right` to have them in opposite of each other.
but for some odd reason i cannot understnd, its not working in the last one.???

p.s I am new to html or coding in general. don't mind the aesthetics of the codes.

```css
#wrapper{
    width: 900px;
 height: 800px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
    font-family: khand,sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold; 
}
#socialmedia1 {
    background-image: url(tw.png);  
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
    margin:38px 10px 0px 0px;

}
#socialmedia2 {
    background-image: url(fb.png);  
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
    margin: 38px 10px 0px 0px;
}
#socialmedia3 {
    background-image: url(insta.png);  
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
    margin: 30px 10px 0px 0px;

}  
 header{
    width: 800px;
 height: 70px;
 border: 3px solid black;
 bottom: 20px;
 position: relative;    /* Had to move this to the bottom
                            to make space for icons*/
 bottom: -40px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
  
 }
 hr{
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 2px;


 }
 .logo{
 background-image :url(logo.png);
 background-size: 140px 140px;
 width: 140px;
 height:140px;
 position:relative;
 bottom: 35px;
 left: 20px;
 }
ul{ 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 450px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 20px;
}
li a {
 display: block;
 color: black;
 padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
 background-color: #911111;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
aside{
 width: 120px;       /*logo overlaps gotta use position relative..EDIT Nevermind i could*
 just add margin to make space without fucking erthing up*/
 height: 150px;
 border: 3px solid black; 
    margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
aside.right{
    width: 120px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    float: right;

}
.titlebannerbox{
 width: 120px;
 height: 25px;
 background-color: #911111;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 17px;
    color: white;

 }
.asidelogo{
   width: 27px;
   height: 27px;
   background-size: 27px 27px;
   background-image: url(titlebannerlogo.png);
   position: relative;
   bottom: 60px;
   margin-bottom: -65px; 
}
footer {
 width: 800px;
 height: 70px;
 border: 3px solid black;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto; 
 margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khand:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="style.css">
<style>
</style>
</head>
  <body> 
     <div id="wrapper">
       <header> 
           <a href="https://twitter.com" id="socialmedia1"></a>
           <a href="https://facebook.com" id="socialmedia2"></a>
           <a href="https://youtube.com" id="socialmedia3"></a>       
         <div class="logo"></div>    
       </header>
        <nav> 
         <ul>
           <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
         </ul> 
       </nav>
     <aside class="right">
           <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Salary</p>
           <p class="asidelogo"></p>
           <hr>
           <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5px;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 10%">Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$109k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Object C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$108k</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Python</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$100k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$94k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C++</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$93k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$91k</td>
             </tr>
               <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$90k</td>
             </tr>
           </table>          
       </aside>
       <aside>
         <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Learned</p>
           <p class="asidelogo"></p>
           <hr>
           <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5px;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 10%">HTML</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">60%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>CSS</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">60%</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">0.001%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">0%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>PhP</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">0%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">0%</td>
             </tr>
           </table>
     </aside>
       <aside class="right">
           <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Salary</p>
           <p class="asidelogo"></p>
           <hr>
           <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5px;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 10%">Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$109k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Object C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$108k</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Python</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$100k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$94k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C++</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$93k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$91k</td>
             </tr>
               <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$90k</td>
             </tr>
           </table>          
       </aside>
       <aside style="color:black">  
         <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Popularity</p>   
         <p class="asidelogo"></p>
         <hr>
           <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 10%">Python</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">31.2%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">19.6%</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C++</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">9.8%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C#</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">7.4%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">7.1%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">6.5%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">6.1%</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
       </aside>
       <aside class="right">
           <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Salary</p>
           <p class="asidelogo"></p>
           <hr>
           <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5px;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 10%">Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$109k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Object C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$108k</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Python</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$100k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$94k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C++</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$93k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$91k</td>
             </tr>
               <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$90k</td>
             </tr>
           </table>          
       </aside>
       <aside>
         <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Difficulty</p>
         <p class="asidelogo"></p>
         <hr>
         <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 30%;">C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;vertical-align: sub;">*****</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C+++</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">*****</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">****</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C#</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">***</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">**</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Python</td>
               <td style="text-align:right;">*</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">*</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
       </aside>
     </div> <!-- End of Wrapper-->
       
        


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use CSS "clear:right;" only last section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your :

```
aside.right{
    width: 120px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    float: right;
}
```

with this one :

```
aside.right{
    width: 120px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    float: right;
    clear:right;
}
```

PS: 
- I added the clear: right; line
- After each float:right, you have to reset the floating element, by using clear: right, so the next element which positioned below will be drawn from the left, just the same as the above elements

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7j2c4tyr/)**

Use this

```
aside.left{
    width: 120px;       
    height: 150px;
    border: 3px solid black;    
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

HTML Structure should be like this:

```
 <aside class="left">...</aside>
```

instead of

```
aside{
        width: 120px;       
        height: 150px;
        border: 3px solid black;    
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
```

HTML Structure:

```
   <aside>...</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can shift left and right aside block with this css,
Please use this css-

aside.right { clear: both; }
aside { float: left; }

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-bottom:15px` from `aside` tag

```css
#wrapper{
    width: 900px;
 height: 800px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
    font-family: khand,sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold; 
}
#socialmedia1 {
    background-image: url(tw.png);  
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
    margin:38px 10px 0px 0px;

}
#socialmedia2 {
    background-image: url(fb.png);  
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
    margin: 38px 10px 0px 0px;
}
#socialmedia3 {
    background-image: url(insta.png);  
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
    margin: 30px 10px 0px 0px;

}  
 header{
    width: 800px;
 height: 70px;
 border: 3px solid black;
 bottom: 20px;
 position: relative;    /* Had to move this to the bottom
                            to make space for icons*/
 bottom: -40px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
  
 }
 hr{
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 2px;


 }
 .logo{
 background-image :url(logo.png);
 background-size: 140px 140px;
 width: 140px;
 height:140px;
 position:relative;
 bottom: 35px;
 left: 20px;
 }
ul{ 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 450px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 20px;
}
li a {
 display: block;
 color: black;
 padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
 background-color: #911111;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
aside{
 width: 120px;       /*logo overlaps gotta use position relative..EDIT Nevermind i could*
 just add margin to make space without fucking erthing up*/
 height: 150px;
 border: 3px solid black; 
    /*margin-top: 15px; */
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
aside.right{
    width: 120px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    float: right;

}
.titlebannerbox{
 width: 120px;
 height: 25px;
 background-color: #911111;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 17px;
    color: white;

 }
.asidelogo{
   width: 27px;
   height: 27px;
   background-size: 27px 27px;
   background-image: url(titlebannerlogo.png);
   position: relative;
   bottom: 60px;
   margin-bottom: -65px; 
}
footer {
 width: 800px;
 height: 70px;
 border: 3px solid black;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto; 
 margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khand:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="style.css">
<style>
</style>
</head>
  <body> 
     <div id="wrapper">
       <header> 
           <a href="https://twitter.com" id="socialmedia1"></a>
           <a href="https://facebook.com" id="socialmedia2"></a>
           <a href="https://youtube.com" id="socialmedia3"></a>       
         <div class="logo"></div>    
       </header>
        <nav> 
         <ul>
           <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
         </ul> 
       </nav>
     <aside class="right">
           <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Salary</p>
           <p class="asidelogo"></p>
           <hr>
           <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5px;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 10%">Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$109k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Object C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$108k</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Python</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$100k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$94k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C++</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$93k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$91k</td>
             </tr>
               <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$90k</td>
             </tr>
           </table>          
       </aside>
       <aside>
         <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Learned</p>
           <p class="asidelogo"></p>
           <hr>
           <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5px;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 10%">HTML</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">60%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>CSS</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">60%</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">0.001%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">0%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>PhP</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">0%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">0%</td>
             </tr>
           </table>
     </aside>
       <aside class="right">
           <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Salary</p>
           <p class="asidelogo"></p>
           <hr>
           <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5px;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 10%">Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$109k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Object C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$108k</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Python</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$100k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$94k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C++</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$93k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$91k</td>
             </tr>
               <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$90k</td>
             </tr>
           </table>          
       </aside>
       <aside style="color:black">  
         <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Popularity</p>   
         <p class="asidelogo"></p>
         <hr>
           <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 10%">Python</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">31.2%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">19.6%</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C++</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">9.8%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C#</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">7.4%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">7.1%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">6.5%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">6.1%</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
       </aside>
       <aside class="right">
           <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Salary</p>
           <p class="asidelogo"></p>
           <hr>
           <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5px;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 10%">Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$109k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Object C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$108k</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Python</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$100k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$94k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C++</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$93k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$91k</td>
             </tr>
               <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$90k</td>
             </tr>
           </table>          
       </aside>
       <aside>
         <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Difficulty</p>
         <p class="asidelogo"></p>
         <hr>
         <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 30%;">C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;vertical-align: sub;">*****</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C+++</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">*****</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">****</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C#</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">***</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">**</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Python</td>
               <td style="text-align:right;">*</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">*</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
       </aside>
     </div> <!-- End of Wrapper-->
       
        


  </body>
</html>
```